# perform DOM iteration only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table row with a button in a cell. When I click that button I want to assign the text inside each other cell of the same row to a variable. So if I have 5 cells I'll have 4 variables (the 5th is for the button).

What I do now is:

```
$('.save').click(function(e){
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.id').text();
    var x = $(this).closest('tr').find('.x').text()
});
```

`this` refers to the button so I have to navigate up to the containing `tr` and down to each cell. Is there a way to avoid having to traverse the dom for each variable? In other words, to focus on that row without repeating each time `$(this).closest('tr')`?
NOTE: I am not referring to just writing it but to the action that is behind. So something like `var row = $(this).closest('tr')` is not a solution since anyway the action of looking for the row will be performed again.

Comment: what makes you think "var row = $(this).closest('tr') is not a solution since anyway the action of looking for the row will be performed again." ?   That isn't how jquery selectors work in my limited understanding.

Comment: Well, you could use `$(".save").each(function(){ var row = $(this).closest("tr"); $(this).click;...` but it doesn't make sense to complexify your code here. The time to look for the parent is irrelevant.

Comment: @DanFarrell if in my code I replace `$(this).closest('tr')` with `row` I am just using a placeholder for my code readibility, or I am missing something?

Comment: Side note: "*change the scope for 'this' in a function"* `this` and scope have very little to do with one another, other than that fact `this` cannot change within a scope. `this` is effectively a special function argument. Scope relates to identifier resolution.

Comment: Don't you think you should post HTML as well? Then you wouldn't need to write paragraphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So something like `var row = $(this).closest('tr')` is not a solution since anyway the action of looking for the row will be performed again.

No, it won't. It will be performed **once** (when the click occurs), and the *result* of that (a jQuery object wrapped around the `tr` element) is stored in the `row` variable. So that's exactly how you do it.

```
$('.save').click(function(e){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var id = row.find('.id').text();
    var x = row.find('.x').text()
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I supposed I was just using a "placeholder" for the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think `var tr = $(this).closest("tr")` will do the trick as you dont have to go for that row again.

Answer (score -1):

Use `dataset` attributes to extend your button markup with required data to be used when click occurs:

```
<button data-id="some-id" data-x="some-x" ...>
```

So you can generate this button with required attributes and do not need always inspect DOM.

```
$('.save').click(function(e){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var x = $(this).data('x');
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what i am asking for. Table cells are contenteditable so i want to grab the updated value